# Handling Exceptions for ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, exception, threadpoolexecutor

I have the following code snippet that basically scans through the list of task that needs to be executed and each task is then given to the executor for execution.

The `JobExecutor` in turn creates another executor (for doing db stuff...reading and writing data to queue) and completes the task.

`JobExecutor` returns a `Future<Boolean>` for the tasks submitted. When one of the task fails, I want to gracefully interrupt all the threads and shutdown the executor by catching all the exceptions. What changes do I need to do?

```
public class DataMovingClass {
    private static final AtomicInteger uniqueId = new AtomicInteger(0);

  private static final ThreadLocal<Integer> uniqueNumber = new IDGenerator();   

  ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor  = null ;

   private List<Source> sources = new ArrayList<Source>();

    private static class IDGenerator extends ThreadLocal<Integer> {
        @Override
        public Integer get() {
            return uniqueId.incrementAndGet();
        }
  }

  public void init(){

    // load sources list

  }

  public boolean execute() {

    boolean succcess = true ; 
    threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10,10,
                10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1024),
                new ThreadFactory() {
                    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                        Thread t = new Thread(r);
                        t.setName("DataMigration-" + uniqueNumber.get());
                        return t;
                    }// End method
                }, new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());

     List<Future<Boolean>> result = new ArrayList<Future<Boolean>>();

     for (Source source : sources) {
                    result.add(threadPoolExecutor.submit(new JobExecutor(source)));
     }

     for (Future<Boolean> jobDone : result) {
                try {
                    if (!jobDone.get(100000, TimeUnit.SECONDS) && success) {
                        // in case of successful DbWriterClass, we don't need to change
                        // it.
                        success = false;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // handle exceptions
                }
            }

  }

  public class JobExecutor implements Callable<Boolean>  {

        private ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor ;
        Source jobSource ;
        public SourceJobExecutor(Source source) {
            this.jobSource = source;
            threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10,10,10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1024),
                    new ThreadFactory() {
                        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                            Thread t = new Thread(r);
                            t.setName("Job Executor-" + uniqueNumber.get());
                            return t;
                        }// End method
                    }, new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        }

        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            boolean status = true ; 
            System.out.println("Starting Job = " + jobSource.getName());
            try {

                        // do the specified task ; 


            }catch (InterruptedException intrEx) {
                logger.warn("InterruptedException", intrEx);
                status = false ;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                logger.fatal("Exception occurred while executing task "+jobSource.getName(),e);
                status = false ;
            }
           System.out.println("Ending Job = " + jobSource.getName());
            return status ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you submit a task to the executor, it returns you a [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) instance.

[`FutureTask.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#get%28%29) will re-throw any exception thrown by the task as an `ExecutorException`.

So when you iterate through the `List<Future>` and call get on each, catch `ExecutorException` and invoke an orderly shutdown.

Comment: ok..do you see any other flaws or places where I need to handle exceptions?

Answer (score 15):

Since you are submitting tasks to `ThreadPoolExecutor`, the exceptions are getting swallowed by `FutureTask`.

Have a look at this [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java)

```
**Inside FutureTask$Sync**

void innerRun() {
    if (!compareAndSetState(READY, RUNNING))
        return;

  runner = Thread.currentThread();
    if (getState() == RUNNING) { // recheck after setting thread
        V result;
       try {
            result = callable.call();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
           setException(ex);
            return;
        }
       set(result);
    } else {
        releaseShared(0); // cancel
    }
```

}

```
protected void setException(Throwable t) {
   sync.innerSetException(t);
}
```

From above code, it is clear that `setException` method catching `Throwable`. Due to this reason, `FutureTask` is swallowing all exceptions if you use "`submit()`" method on `ThreadPoolExecutor`

As per java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute-java.lang.Runnable-java.lang.Throwable-), you can extend `afterExecute()` method in `ThreadPoolExecutor`

```
protected void afterExecute(Runnable r,
                            Throwable t)
```

Sample code as per documentation:

```
class ExtendedExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
   // ...
   protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
     super.afterExecute(r, t);
     if (t == null && r instanceof Future<?>) {
       try {
         Object result = ((Future<?>) r).get();
       } catch (CancellationException ce) {
           t = ce;
       } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
           t = ee.getCause();
       } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
           Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // ignore/reset
       }
     }
     if (t != null)
       System.out.println(t);
   }
 }
```

You can catch `Exceptions` in three ways

1. `Future.get()` as suggested in accepted answer
2. wrap entire `run()` or `call()` method in `try{}catch{}Exceptoion{}` blocks
3. override  `afterExecute` of `ThreadPoolExecutor`  method as shown above

To gracefully interrupt other Threads, have a look at below SE question:

[How to stop next thread from running in a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318461/how-to-stop-next-thread-from-running-in-a-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor/37319899#37319899)

[How to forcefully shutdown java ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644043/how-to-forcefully-shutdown-java-executorservice/36644320#36644320)

Comment: the 3rd approach `afterExecute` is fit for me, thanks

Comment: Does this apply to only `ThreadPoolExecutor` and not to any other implementations of `ExecutorService`?

Comment: It applies to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html and its derived classes

Comment: If you are applying this logic to `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and calling `scheduleAtFixedRate` or `scheduleWithFixedDelay` then you are in trouble as the `((Future<?>) r).get();` will never return leading to exhaustion of the threads in the pool. Simple fix could be to change the condition to, `if (t == null && r instanceof Future<?> && !r.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("ScheduledFutureTask")) {` . As `ScheduledFutureTask` is a private class, you cant check with `instanceof`.

Answer (score 3):

Subclass `ThreadPoolExecutor` and override its `protected afterExecute (Runnable r, Throwable t)` method.

If you're creating a thread pool via the `java.util.concurrent.Executors` convenience class (which you're not), take at look at its source to see how it's invoking  [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).