# Java multithreaded programming using with Guava FutureCallback interface

Tags: java, multithreading, guava

My question is related to java multithreaded programming.
I am dealing with main thread that creates many workers, every worker is a thread.
To get results/errors from workers to main thread i used with Callable and Future.
I did find in guava [FutureCallback](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureCallback.html) interface to get exceptions from worker. 
My question is how to use it, because I didn't find any examples on the web.
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example with Integer results:

```
ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4));
int runs = 100;
for (int k=0; k < runs; k++) {
    Callable<Integer> job = ...; // create the job here
    ListenableFuture<Integer> completion = executor.submit(job);
    Futures.addCallback(completion, new FutureCallback<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            // log error
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Integer result) {
            // do something with the result
        }

    });
}
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4) - means that in every moment can be only 4 running threads ?

Comment: It is an executor that has exactly 4 threads. Just look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html . There are different implementations that you can create.

Comment: you have int runs = 100; it's mean that in loop(for) there will be some kind of sleep to wait for executor can get new job ?

Comment: No, it just means that the loop is run 100 times. You have to adapt it to your own requirements of course.

Comment: So as I understand, there are 100 jobs that can be run in 4 threads ?

Comment: Yes. 100 jobs are submitted to the executor. And in this case the executor will run those jobs with 4 different threads. But all this is transparent to you. You don't need to care what the executor is really doing.