# Stop execution on server and client on HttpClient TimeoutException

Tags: java, multithreading, httpclient

In Java I'm using `HttpClient`, and I have set a connection timeout and socket timeout for this object. When I call the `execute` method, it hits my server-side code, which creates an another thread to handle my server logic,  and if socket timeout exception occurs, my client-side is going into `catch`, where I stop further execution, and my server-side thread executes through the end of the code.

Is there any way I can stop execution on my server-side, if connection timeout occurs.

Comment: Check this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318461/how-to-stop-next-thread-from-running-in-a-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor/37319899#37319899

Comment: Thanks @Ravindrababu, the above post helps me to understand how to stop the execution on server, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my code basically my client is a java file which performs httpClient.execute -> which calls a servlet and in servlet doPost is executing. At the client execution goes into catch after timeout but my servlet still keeps on executing without any exception

Comment: I don't think you can achieve it.